# BigQuery raises exception if query with joins are not flattened

Tags: google-bigquery

Query is:

```
select
    cb.subnum as subnum,
    last(
        if(
            (if(cu.smartcard_number is not null, 1, 0)) +
            (if(rr.smart_card_number is not null, 1, 0)) > 0, 1, 0)   
    ) as econnected_i,

from 
    combined.table1 as cb

left outer join each dataflow_raw_eu.table2 as cu
on cu.smartcard_number = cb.smart_card_num

left outer join each dataflow_raw_eu.table3 as rr
on rr.smart_card_number = cb.smart_card_num

group by subnum
```

The error is:

> Error: Ambiguous field name 'imported_at' in JOIN. Please use the table qualifier before field name.

I noticed that when it runs with only one join, of either table, then the query succeeds. `imported_at` is a timestamp field shared by all 3 tables (the only field shared by all 3), but it is not included in the query.

If I select `flatten_results` in the BigQuery options, then the query succeeds; but I wish to run future queries with nested records. None of the tables in the above query have a repeated or record field.

Comment: Could you post a job ID

Comment: @Pentium10 `multichoice-insights:job_PQxAroX-vhDr4vjCl0HCehxVqD8`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this can be GBQ bug

Try below for workaround

```
SELECT
    cb.subnum AS subnum,
    LAST(
        IF(
            (IF(cu.smartcard_number IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) +
            (IF(rr.smart_card_number IS NOT NULL, 1, 0)) > 0, 1, 0)   
    ) AS econnected_i,

FROM 
    combined.table1 AS cb

LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (SELECT smartcard_number FROM dataflow_raw_eu.table2) AS cu
ON cu.smartcard_number = cb.smart_card_num

LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (SELECT smart_card_number FROM dataflow_raw_eu.table3) AS rr
ON rr.smart_card_number = cb.smart_card_num

GROUP BY subnum
```

Please note, depends on logic and nature of data in `dataflow_raw_eu.table2` and `dataflow_raw_eu.table3` , you might consider using GROUP BY in subselects, like below

```
SELECT smartcard_number FROM dataflow_raw_eu.table2 GROUP BY smartcard_number
```

and

```
SELECT smart_card_number FROM dataflow_raw_eu.table3 GROUP BY smart_card_number
```

Comment: I added this to the BigQuery issue tracker at https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=415.